# How can I call the ::before in JavaScript by DOM style

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to change pseudo element (::before) style in javaScript by DOM style. How can I do that?

Like this

```
document.getElementById("new-store-nav").style.color= "#000";
```

I have changed this style by calling ID but how can I call ::before in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getComputedStyle` function which is on `window` object

In your case it would be like:

```
const color = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.getElementById("new-store-nav"), ':before'
).getPropertyValue('color')
```

Reference to David Walsh's site [here](https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element#:%7E:text=CSS%20pseudo%2Delements%20are%20incredibly,need%20for%20additional%20HTML%20elements)